# Swift Combine: What are those multicast functions for and how do I use them?

Tags: swift, ios13, combine, macos-catalina

Struggling with some combine problems I came across the "Working with Multiple Subscribers" section in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher :

```swift
func multicast<S>(() -> S) -> Publishers.Multicast<Self, S>

func multicast<S>(subject: S) -> Publishers.Multicast<Self, S>
```

However, when I tried to confirm my assumption that multicast would be needed when sending to multiple subscribers, I found out this is not necessary when trying on this playground code (modified from https://github.com/AvdLee/CombineSwiftPlayground/blob/master/Combine.playground/Pages/Combining%20Publishers.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift ) (run on 10.14.5 in Xcode Version 11.0 beta 3 (11M362v)):

```swift
enum FormError: Error { }

let usernamePublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, FormError>()
let passwordPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, FormError>()

let validatedCredentials = Publishers.CombineLatest(usernamePublisher, passwordPublisher)
    .map { (username, password) -> (String, String) in
        return (username, password)
    }
    .map { (username, password) -> Bool in
        !username.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty && password.count > 12
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

let firstSubscriber = validatedCredentials.sink { (valid) in
    print("First Subscriber: CombineLatest: Are the credentials valid: \(valid)")
}

let secondSubscriber = validatedCredentials.sink { (valid) in
    print("Second Subscriber: CombineLatest: Are the credentials valid: \(valid)")
}

// Nothing will be printed yet as `CombineLatest` requires both publishers to have send at least one value.
usernamePublisher.send("avanderlee")
passwordPublisher.send("weakpass")
passwordPublisher.send("verystrongpassword")
```

This prints:

```
First Subscriber: CombineLatest: Are the credentials valid: false
Second Subscriber: CombineLatest: Are the credentials valid: false
First Subscriber: CombineLatest: Are the credentials valid: true
Second Subscriber: CombineLatest: Are the credentials valid: true
```

so it seems that no multicast is needed to address multiple subscribers. Or I am wrong?

So, what are those multicast functions for and how would I use them? Some example code would be nice.

Thanks,

Lars

Answer (score 5):

PassthroughSubject is not a very good example to test with, because it's a class and gives you reference semantics. Therefore in a simple case two subscribers can subscribe directly to it and receive the same values at the same time whenever the subject emits one.

But here's a better test case (inspired by a discussion on [Cocoa With Love](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/twenty-two-short-tests-of-combine-part-2.html)):

```
    let pub1 = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
    let sub = CurrentValueSubject<Int,Never>(0)
    let scan = sub.scan(10) {i,j in i+j}
    pub1.sink { _ in let i = sub.value; sub.value = i+1 }.store(in:&storage)
    scan.sink { print("a", $0) }.store(in:&storage)
    delay(3) {
        scan.sink { print("b", $0) }.store(in:&self.storage)
    }
```

That gives a decidedly weird result when the second `sink` comes along as a new subscriber to this pipeline:

```
a 10
a 11
a 13
a 16
b 13
a 20
b 17
a 25
b 22
a 31
b 28
a 38
b 35
```

Sinks `a` and `b` are getting a different series of numbers from one another, effectively because `scan` is a struct. If we want them to get the same numbers, we can use a multicast:

```
    let scan = sub.scan(10) {i,j in i+j}.multicast {PassthroughSubject()}.autoconnect()
```

That yields

```
a 10
a 11
a 13
a 16
a 20
b 20
a 25
b 25
```

which is coherent.

However, that *still* doesn't prove you need `multicast`, because you could accomplish the same thing by saying `.share()` instead. I'm not clear on what the difference is between `multicast` and `share`.

Comment: Multicast() and share() are almost the same. The difference is shared() will create subscription when the first subscription subscibed, it causes the second subscription can miss some values if it is subscribed after value emitted. The multicast() can delay the subscription to the upstream, by not call autoconnect like you did, instead, call connect() after second subscription is set up.

Answer (score 0):

[An answer/reference from the swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/combine-what-are-those-multicast-functions-for/26677/9) implies that the multicast methods are meant to build upon the .share() operator. From [Philippe's post](https://forums.swift.org/t/combine-what-are-those-multicast-functions-for/26677/3):

> In that case it used to connect an upstream to a PassthroughSubject and then is auto connected. Normally when a Subscriber receives a Subscription it will cancel any additional Subscriptions past the first, Multicast gives an escape hatch to this behavior and handles multiple Subscriptions.

In practice, if you want to split a stream and multicast event updates through multiple pipelines in Combine, it seems the most pragmatic way is to create a @Published property, having any upstream pipeline update it with .assign() or within .sink(), and then set up additional pipelines with subscribers from the @Published property.