# Swift Combine's CombineLatest does not fire in response to an update to one of its publishers

Tags: swift, combine, combinelatest

I am combining two publishers to determine what the center coordinate of a map view should be. The two publishers are:

1. The user's initial location determined by a `CLLocationManager` (the first location reported once the `CLLocationManager` begins sending location updates).
2. The user's current location if the "center map on current location" button is tapped.

In code:

```
    class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

        // The first location reported by the CLLocationManager.
        @Published var initialUserCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
        // The latest location reported by the CLLocationManager.
        @Published var currentUserCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
        // What the current map view center should be.
        @Published var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.35843, longitude: -71.05977) // Default coordinate.

        // A subject whose `send(_:)` method is being called elsewhere every time the user presses a button to center the map on the user's location.
        var centerButtonTappedPublisher: PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never> = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()

        // The combined publisher that is where all my troubles lie.
        var coordinatePublisher: AnyPublisher<CLLocationCoordinate2D, Never> {
            Publishers.CombineLatest($initialUserCoordinate, centerButtonTappedPublisher)
                .map { initialCoord, centerButtonTapped in
                    var latestCoord = initialCoord
                    if centerButtonTapped {
                        latestCoord = self.currentUserCoordinate
                    }
                    return latestCoord
                }
                .replaceNil(with: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.35843, longitude: -71.05977))
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }

        private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

        //... Other irrelevant properties

        private override init() {
            super.init()

            coordinatePublisher
                .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
                .assign(to: \.coordinate, on: self)
                .store(in: &cancellableSet)

            //... CLLocationManager set-up
        }
    }

    extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        //...

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            // We are only interested in the user's most recent location.
            guard let location = locations.last else { return }
            let latestCoord = location.coordinate
            if initialUserCoordinate == nil {
                initialUserCoordinate = latestCoord
            }
            currentUserCoordinate = latestCoord
        }

        //...

    }
```

Both publishers, `$initialUserCoordinate` and `centerButtonTappedPublisher`, publish updates - I have confirmed this. However, the combined publisher `coordinatePublisher` only fires when the "center map on current location" button is tapped. It never fires when the `initialUserCoordinate` property is first set.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910228/swift-combine-subsequent-publisher-that-consumes-other-publishers-using-combin) suggests adding a `.receive(on: RunLoop.main)` after the `Publishers.CombineLatest($initialUserCoordinate, centerButtonTappedPublisher)` but this does not work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`Publishers.Merge`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/merge/3208965-merge) rather than [`CombineLatest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/combinelatest), see the documentation:

For `Publishers.CombineLatest`:

> A publisher that receives and combines the latest elements from two publishers.

For `Publishers.Merge`

> A publisher that emits an event when **either** upstream publisher emits an event.

Comment: Thanks @Sajjon! That does the trick. I had thought that CombineLatest would publish when any of its publishers publish, but apparently all need to publish a new value first. Thanks again!